# webpack, really disable Terser and CSS minification

Tags: webpack

Webpack by default enables Terser and CSS minification that seem to could not be turned off.

Problem that those minifications do not work correctly and produce results I do not want. For example CSS minification is not removing comments like /*! */ and splitted CSS chunks have huge duplicated includes of vendor libraries (e.g bootstrap-vue).

Trying to disable those not making any results. I am logging webpack config on every production build and this is what I get

```
chainWebpack: (config) => {
    console.log(config.optimization.minimizers.store.keys());
    
}
// output: { 'terser', 'css' }
console.log(config.optimization.plugins.store.keys());
{
  'vue-loader',
  'define',
  'case-sensitive-paths',
  'friendly-errors',
  'extract-css', // Why this one is even here ? 
  'copy'
}
```

I do not want these modifications. I want optimization of CSS at least be done by postcss plugins like cssnano.

But webpack can not get it set. It runs terser, it is trying to split chunks even I did not ask for this. It is insisting on doing CSS minification by throwing error

```
Syntax Error: Error: You forgot to add 'mini-css-extract-plugin' plugin (i.e. `{ plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()] }`), please read https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#getting-started
```

I do not want this plugin. I have not asked for it to be turned on. But webpack is asking for it anyway.

```
configureWebpack: (webpack) => {
            return {
                resolve: RESOLVE,
                mode: 'production',
                stats: {warnings: false},

                optimization: {
                    minimizer: [],
                    minimize: false,
                    chunkIds: false,
                    runtimeChunk: 'single',
                    removeEmptyChunks: true,
                    mergeDuplicateChunks: true,
                    removeAvailableModules: true,
                    flagIncludedChunks: false,
                },

                //MODULE config
                module: {

                    rules: [
                        //process scss
                        {
                            test: /\.s|css$/,
                            use: [
                                "postcss-loader",
                                'sass-loader'
                            ],
                        },

                    ],
                },
                output: {
                    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
                    filename: '[name].bundle_[fullhash].js',
                    clean: true,
                },

                plugins: [
       
                    new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
                    //create standard index.html file
                    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                        template: 'public/index.html',
                    }),
                ],

                entry: {
                    index: './src/main.js',
                },


            }
        },
```